# Get folder name and rename file name tr Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, tr

I have a script that changes the file name. It takes a directory name and added to the file name. By the way, using tr replaces a string:

0004 the name of the directory (this directory is a script)
- DSC_1234.jpg

result `0004_1234.jpg`

The script works if I am in a particular directory. I wanted to change a name yet in subdirectories

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=`pwd`
BASENAME=`basename $CURRENT`
echo $BASENAME
for i in ./*DSC*;do mv -- "$i" "${i//DSC/$BASENAME}";done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work in subdirectories:

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do dir="$(dirname ${i#./})"; mv "$i" "${i//DSC/$(basename $dir)}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `find` on your bash script (call that script `your_script.sh`):

```
find $ROOT_DIR -type d -exec your_script.sh \;
```